# Terraform: EC2 instance is still creating after running shell script using provisioner

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, sh

I need some help from Terraform export.
I'm going to create EC2 instance and install some packages on it using terraform.
To install packages, I used the provisiner of terraform. This is a EC2 instance part.

```
resource "aws_instance" "lms_server" {
  ami = var.AMI
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name = var.private_key
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.instance_profile.name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.main-public-1.id
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.security_rule.id]

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "script.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
  }
  
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline  = [
      "chmod +x /tmp/script.sh",
      "/tmp/script.sh ${var.gh_user} ${var.gh_token} ${var.gh_url} ${aws_db_instance.lms_mysql_db.address} ${var.db_name} ${var.db_username} ${var.db_password} ${aws_sqs_queue.lms_queue.id} ${var.sqs_name} ${self.public_ip} ${var.aws_region} ${var.bucket_name}",
    ]
  }
  
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = "${self.public_ip}"
    user        = var.user_name
    private_key = "${file("lms_key.pem")}"
  }
  
  root_block_device {
      volume_size   =   var.volume_size
  }

  tags = {
    lms_app = "lms_server"
  }
}
```

As you can see here, I access the EC2 via SSH and copied `script.sh` file that includes all commands. Then run it. I think EC2 was created successfully and all packages were installed, but terraform CLI keeps `ec2 instance: still creating` status.
This means that the creation of EC2 instance is not finished yet. so If I drop this(`Ctrl+C`) and then run `terraform apply` again, it used to destroy and create instance from the first again. Also it's installing all packages again.

This operation is happening each time I update the terraform script for other, not EC2.

I'm looking forward to getting some help about this problem.
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Try using the `user_data` argument with cloud-init instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us the scripts.sh content? Maybe there is something keep that script executing so that it can not finish.

You can try using user_data instead. It will run your script after the EC2 is created in the bootstrap phase and it is logged in the EC2.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data

Comment: Thanks for your attention. 
After I post this question, I solved soon. I checked all commands of script.sh file one by one. There is a problem in this command `sudo service nginx status`
After I remove this, everything worked well. 
Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Okay, if you post this script.sh at the first time, we will fix it quicker. Have a nice day